# Insert a new column or row in Adobe Illustrator's graph data editor

Tags: adobe-illustrator, information-graphics

Is it possible to insert a new column or row in Adobe Illustrator's graph data editor? (without having to move the existing data through  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>V</kbd>)

[image]

I use Adobe Illustrator CC 17.0.0 64-bit on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you can specifically *insert* a row or column.

You *can* click-drag to highlight multiple cells and copy. Then click-drag to highlight new cells and paste. You don't have to copy/paste one cell at a time.